# ¿Como hacer que la consulta me devuelva un campo según los otros campos que están relacionados a él en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Esta es mi primera pregunta en esta página y perdonad si no soy específico en algunas cosas o no me explico del todo bien.

Vale, estoy utilizando una base de datos en MySQL y tengo un problema al intentar sacar una consulta y que me devuelva lo que yo quiero, seguramente porque mis conocimientos no son los suficientes...

Bien, tengo dos tablas, enfermedades y síntomas las cuales tienen una relación de muchos a muchos, es decir, una enfermedad puede tener 1 o más síntomas y viceversa. Esto lleva a generar otra tabla que relaciona las dos anteriores y es esta (la tabla se llama enfermedades_diagnosticos):

[image: tabla enfermedades_diagnosticos]

Vale, ahora viene el problema, yo quiero sacar el id_enfermedade que corresponda a los síntomas exactos que le paso (si tiene uno más o uno menos ya no sirve), o lo que es igual, que a partir de unos síntomas me devuelva la enfermedad que es.

Por ejemplo: Si le paso los síntomas 5 y 7 quiero que me devuelva:

[image: resultado esperado] o aún mejor   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque la enfermedad 6 tenga también los síntomas 5 y 7 porque no son los únicos que tiene ya que la enfermedad 6 tiene: los síntomas 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Lo único a lo que he llegado es a hacer lo inverso, que a partir de una enfermedad me saque todos los síntomas a los que está asociada.
Con esta select:

`SELECT id_sintoma FROM enfermedades_diagnostico WHERE id_enfermedade=1;`

Pero como ya he mencionado, no me sirve, porque busco lo contrario.

Como ya he comentado mi nivel de SQL es muy bajo y me impide acercarme más.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM enfermedades 
         WHERE id_enfernedade in(SELECT id_enfermedade FROM enfermedades_diagnostico WHERE id_sintoma in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

Lo hice a ojo así que revisa la sintaxis porque puede darte un fallo. Pruebala y me comentas.

Editado:

```
SELECT e.* FROM enfermedades e
         WHERE id_enfernedad in(SELECT ed.id_enfermedad FROM enfermedades_diagnostico ed WHERE ed,id_sintoma in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AND ed.id_enfermedad = e.id_enfermedad);
```

Lo mismo, un vistazo a que los nombre de los campos coincidan con los tuyos.
Prueba y me comentas.

Comment: Hola montes, lo he probado y me dice unknown column id_enfermedade in "IN/ALL/ANY" subquery. Lo he probado cambiando revisando que todo estuviera bien escrito y lo maximo que ha hecho ha sido devolverme todas las enfermedades sin filtrar ninguna

Comment: Ya lo edite, se me olvidó una clausula AND en la subconsulta para relacionarla. Un saludo.

Comment: hola montes, lo he probado y este es el código bien escrito:  <br/> `SELECT e.* FROM enfermedades e
         WHERE id in(SELECT ed.id_enfermedade FROM enfermedades_diagnosticos ed WHERE ed.id_sintoma in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) AND ed.id_enfermedade = e.id);`    (perdona por no formatearlo pero no se añadir saltos de línea en la caja de comentarios)  lo que busco es que por ejemplo, pasandole 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 me encontrase la enfermedad numero 6 ya que es la única que coincide con todos esos sintomas, pero en cambio lo que me devuelve son las enfermedades 1,2,4,5,6,7 :(